# Trying to enable android device for eclipse debugging

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a Galaxy S3 which I set up for android debugging on my Win 7 laptop months ago; I think I might have gotten a sample app running on it, but then didn't do anything else with it.

Today I newly downloaded and installed Android Development Tools, which included eclipse, for a new attempt at Android development.  When I got to the part of the instructions about installing my device so the debugger could run the sample app on it, my phone was already listed in Device Manager, and attempting to update the device driver gave me the message that the driver is up to date.

However, when I follow the instructions for debugging the app on the phone, it gives the message "Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device."

When I run "adb devices", it lists a device as "8005ba15  unauthorized"; I don't know if that's due to the previous installation or if something else is wrong.  I don't know whether I'm supposed to configure something in eclipse or on Windows.

Can anyone point me to how to fix this?

Comment: Your manifest has enabled the option for debug?

Comment: No, in fact it doesn't.  The tutorial didn't mention it, and in fact I don't know that "debugging" is really required.  This is the app that one gets by default in ADT when an Android application is created, so I suppose it's just suppose to run and display "Hello World" without needing breakpoints and so forth.  But I don't know if the manifest has to have that before it will run the application.  Also, the error indicated a lack of a "target device", not a malformed app or manifest.  But I'm willing to try it, I'll look up what the manifest needs for that.

Comment: Further info: I looked for info on how to change the manifest, and found this at http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html: "Declare your application as "debuggable" in your Android Manifest.
When using Eclipse, you can skip this step, because running your app directly from the Eclipse IDE automatically enables debugging."  Just FYI.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Did u enable developer options in ur phone?

Comment: As @JpCrow said,  you must enable the `USB Debug` option in the `Developer Options`. Also, you have to **authorize your computer on your device**.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a definitive answer, though it is now working.  It appears from going through scattered comments on similar problems that there is a "server" that runs on the laptop, an image called "adb" that you have to find in a sub-sub-sub-folder of the android dev tools installation.  By repeatedly unplugging and replugging the phone, disabling and re-enabling debugging on the phone, and stopping and restarting the server, this finally started working (or at least worked the last time I tried it).

It would be a great help if someone, somewhere wrote a piece on "Here is how the eclipse/android debugging stuff works" so that we could figure out what was wrong instead of just trying random stuff.  I was following a tutorial, and although I am grateful for those, they tend to give 1. 2. 3. instructions with no explanation, and as soon as something goes wrong (or is different on your version of eclipse/windows/android/samsung than the one the tutorial used), you're stuck because you don't have anything except those instructions.  Then you need to know things like

1. when you plug your phone into your laptop, assuming the driver is installed, it evidently goes through an authorization based on a key stored on the laptop.  You don't enter the key, it's already there.  At that point, a popup appears on the phone asking you to authorize control of the phone by the laptop, including an option not to ask you each time.
2. If the server is running and something goes wrong, it is possible for the server to get hung up, and will need to be stopped and restarted.
3. there is something in the ADT within eclipse that either is a server or uses the adb server -- anyway, it repeatedly runs something within eclipse that will give you error messages unless you have the rest of it working.  I don't know if it starts when I start eclipse/adt, or whether it starts when I  start an application.

My thanks to the commenters attempting to point me right.  You all helped.